# Wrap Antd's Input with iMaskInput mixin set correct ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, maskedinput

I want to wrap an Input component from Ant design with IMask component using IMaskInput.
To get it work correctly I have to provide proper ref to IMask mixin. But the problem is in that Antd Input has custom elements sctructure and I don't know how to access native input's ref and pass it.
I've read react ref's documentation several times but still have no clue.

Example of my code (it's a part of class component's render function):

```
const MaskedAntedInput = IMaskMixin(({inputRef, ...props}: any) => (
                            <Input
                                {...props}
                                onChange={this.onInputChange}
                                value={stateValue}
                                disabled={disabled}
                                style={{backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor}}
                                allowClear={true}
                                ref={inputRef}
                            />
                        ))

                        return (
                            <MaskedAntedInput
                                inputRef={(ref: any) => {this.maskedRef = ref}}
                                mask={mask}
                                onAccept={this.onMaskedInputChange}
                                disabled={disabled}
                                value={stateValue}
                                unmask={true}
                                lazy={false}
                            />
                        )
```

I get error:
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
I understand why I get this error but I can't find proper way to get and pass correct element's ref.